# Designing data structure which can decrease range in lgn

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was asked in an exercise to design a data structure which can handle the following methods in logarithmic time complexity (lgn):

- Insert(x): Inserts x to the data structure
- Find(x): Finds if x exists in the data structre
- Decrease(x, y): Adds **negative value y (y<0)** to all the keys which are smaller than x

So, the two first are easy to implement using a Balanced Search Tree.
But the last method (Decrease) is very tricky and I didn't find any idea for doing it in a logarithmic time complexity...

Would be happy to hear some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt such a data structure exists, because the `Deacrease(x, y)` function may need to visit all the data/keys stored in the data structure, when `x` is greater that all the data/keys stored in the data structure.

Comment: My lecture mentioned that it's possible... So I believe it's very tricky but applicable...
I guess that passing all the keys isn't the best approach for this mission...
Thought about holding another tree of ranges.... but got stacked at this point